# Texture mapping issue

Tags: texturing

I have some problem with mapping a brick texture to the house model. I recently started learning blender  and I don't know how to fix this. Once the textures were displayed correctly, but I don't remember how i did it. [image]

Comment: hello, you first need to unwrap your object, it will decide how the image is projected on the walls

Answer (score 1):

1)Go into edit mode
2)Select everything with "A"
3)Hit "U"
4)Do "smart UV project"
5)Now split the window with one side being UV editor and the other - 3d view that's set to material preview.
6)In edit mode select the faces that look funky or wrong, go to UV editor and scale, rotate and move around the face there until it looks good in 3d viewport